# How do I get the key of the currently loaded item in a FormView from a separate user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView from which another user control is launched.

The FormView loads an "order" from the database.
The UserControl contains a form to insert line items for this order.

When inserting a line item, I need the order ID to associate the line items to the order.

But since the child control is a separate user control, the FormView is not visible and inaccessible.  Does anyone know how I can go about getting the FormViews key value from a different user control?

Using a session or cookie is out of the question unfortunately.

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not simply have a property OrderId on the UserControl?

The FormView can set this property to the current order id.

Comment: That would definitely work. I guess what I'm wondering is how do I get at that value in the code behind? Create a new instance of the order's user control?  Then call the property?

Comment: @Kevin, difficult to say without seeing your existing code and markup.  There are lots of ways of doing it - e.g. data binding or setting the property procedurally in the codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many ways to pass values between controls

1. You can call public method of user control to pass value
2. You can use public property
3. Most simple way you can use session to pass value and after getting value you can again assign null to session to get the memory recollected by garbage collector